# Trying to understand the concept of salting a password

Tags: passwords, cryptography

I understand that if we just hash a password, a hacker could use a pre calculated hashed password table and compare it to the actual hashed password table. From what I understand if we add a random string as a salt before hashing, the pre calculated hash table won't work.

Now my question is, suppose a users password is "password", I add 999 to it and hash the string "password999" before saving it. Now when the user returns to my site, how do I know that I need to add 999 to his password before it is compared to the hashed values in the database? Do I maintain a separate table with all the salts for every username?

Comment: you may have salt calculated from other constant user data like id, or store it independently the latter is more secure

Comment: 2Alexey: I think generation of random salt and storing it is way secure than calculating it from other constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the salt for each user in a separate *column* next to the password.

Comment: ...or in the same column; it's quite common to store hashed passwords in a format that looks something like `salt:hash`. Both ways will work just fine; as far as the database is concerned, password hashes are just opaque blobs anyway.